# JetBrains IDEs tab switcher order

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is it possible to switch file tabs in JetBrains IDEs using <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> in order like Google Chrome? (I'm using PhpStorm atm)

When I press <kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd> it opens the Switcher: the order of tabs is with the most-recent files at the top, the least recent files at the bottom.

Can I configure the IDE somehow to let me switch tabs in the same order they are opened, and displayed in the top tab bar (like the default Google Chrome tab behaviour is)?

Comment: You can just use `Alt + Arrow Left/Right` (or whatever shortcuts you may have there for `Window | Editor Tabs | Select Next/Previous Tab` actions). As far as I know there is no such ordering option for Switcher. If you need to find specific file -- just start typing the name to get the list filtered (also works in `View | Recent Files` and alike -- they are better when you have lots of tabs otherwise you have to press Tab quite few times in Switcher)

Comment: If you have small number of tabs opened .. you can check last comments in [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324) so you can use `Cmd/Ctrl+1,2,3..` to select specific editor tab -- just like Chrome/Firefox can do.

Comment: For some reason `Alt + Left/Right` isn't working for me on Mac OS X, but `Command + Shift + [` and `Command + Shift + ]` are working. Even though those shortcuts are a bit complicated XD

Comment: I'm not a Mac user so cannot say what the deal with `Alt+Left/Right`. Possibly it has special meaning in actual OS or used by IDE for something else. If it's used in IDE then you can check it at `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` -- it has "Search by shortcut" button (next to search field) so you can see what actions are mapped to those shortcuts. You can also assign any other (more convenient) shortcuts to those actions.